# How can I count the Sundays in the current month?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266, sparkcore

I made a LED wall clock & calendar based on arduino a while back and am now wanting to modify it to add in a variable to automatically adjust the offset for DST.  I'm already polling an internet time server 2x per day to ensure accuracy, but time servers generally don't supply DST information.  The change occurs on the 2nd Sunday in March and the 1st Sunday in November. (https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/popular-links/daylight-saving-time-dst)  Essentially I need to know when it is the 2nd Sunday of March and tell it to adjust the time zone offset by +1, then by -1 on the 1st Sunday in November. I'm just not sure how to implement this.

I'm thinking something like:

if 
month == 3 or 11
AND
if weekday == 1;
then
sunday + 1;
else
sunday = 0;

if sunday == 2; 
AND
month == 3;
then
isDST = TRUE;

if sunday == 1;
AND
month == 11;
then 
isDST = FALSE;

I hope this is a good enough example of what I'm wanting to do.  I hate to use so many nested if's but this is the best I can come up with still being a relative novice. Would this even work or is there a better way to go about it?  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In some embedded systems of telecom, DST was always considered a 'local' option.  Thus, those systems provided a user command to enable / disable DST, per facility / state / municipality preferences.

Comment: In the telecom systems, DST was enabled (or not) by the user, and the DST setting changed the time display or time of reports, and changed the user's prompt and guidance for manually setting the clock.  It has been a while, so I'm not sure, but I think the auto update of time (from user specified time server) was something where DST had no meaning.

Comment: Do you have C++11 available?

Comment: To correctly determine the start and end of DST in the US you need to download and parse the Congressional Record.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [paper with calendrical algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) that can be used to compute things like the 2nd Sunday in March.  See [Example: Finding nth weekday of month](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#Example:%20%20Finding%20nth%20weekday%20of%20month).

If you have C++11 available, you can use this [free, open-source date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to compute such things with very high-level syntax.  The library uses the algorithms from [the paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) under the hood.  For example:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
DST_US(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp, std::chrono::hours std_offset)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const auto y = year_month_day{floor<days>(tp)}.year();
    const auto begin = sys_days{sun[2]/mar/y} + 2h - std_offset; // DT begins at this UTC time
    const auto end   = sys_days{sun[1]/nov/y} + 1h - std_offset; // ST begins at this UTC time
    if (tp < begin || end <= tp)
        return tp + std_offset;
    return tp + std_offset + 1h;
}
```

Feel free to use the datetime library if you have C++11 (it is portable), and to create your own using the algorithms in [the paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) otherwise.

Disclaimer:  Timezone rules change all the time.  The above is certainly sufficient for a homemade clock.  For industrial strength applications needing up-to-date timezone rules, use a library based on the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) such as [this one](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here, I made a C++ code for you. You don't need C++11 to run this.

How it works is, it gets the current month and year. Checks if the year is a leap year, then goes ahead and sets max day amount. Let's say 2017 August. The max day will be 31.

Program starts to run through and counts `sundayCounter` up if the day it hit is a sunday.

This way you'll get the amount of sundays in the current month, automatically.

Here's my code, feel free to use it. It does exactly what you want to do. Your desired variable is `sundayCounter`. Have fun.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool isLeap = false;
    int sundayCounter = 0;
    int MAX_DAY;
    int month, year;
    string monthText;

    time_t theTime = time(NULL);
    struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);
    month = aTime->tm_mon;
    year = aTime->tm_year;

    if (year % 4 == 0)
        {;
            if (year % 100 == 0)
            {
                if (year % 400 == 0)
                    isLeap = true;
                else
                    isLeap = false;
            }
            else
                isLeap = true;
        }
    else {
        isLeap = false;
    }

    switch(month)
    {
    case 0:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    case 1:
        if(isLeap)
            MAX_DAY = 29;
        else
            MAX_DAY = 28;
        break;
    case 2:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    case 3:
        MAX_DAY = 30;
        break;
    case 4:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    case 5:
        MAX_DAY = 30;
        break;
    case 6:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    case 7:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    case 8:
        MAX_DAY = 30;
        break;
    case 9:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    case 10:
        MAX_DAY = 30;
        break;
    case 11:
        MAX_DAY = 31;
        break;
    }

    for(int day = 0; day <= MAX_DAY; day++) {
        struct tm time_in = { 0, 0, 0, // second, minute, hour
                day, month + 1, year - 1900 }; // 1-based day, 0-based month, year since 1900

        time_t time_temp = mktime( & time_in );

        // the return value from localtime is a static global - do not call
        // this function from more than one thread!
        tm const *time_out = localtime( & time_temp );

        switch(time_out->tm_wday)
        {
        case 0:
            sundayCounter++;
            break;
        }
    }

    const char* month_list[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    int current_month = month+1;
    const char* current_month_name = month_list[current_month-1];
    cout << "Sunday amount in " << current_month_name << " " << (year + 1900) << ": " << sundayCounter;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sunday amount in August 2017: 4
```